# Adding info to buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

Im looking to add information to these buttons below so when pressed the info appears.... I've been trying to us the get() feature for this, is this correct? I can't seem to get it to run but heres my attempt of code:

```
submit = Button(frame, text="Enter", width=15, command=lambda: valueGET(E1.get(), E2.get())) 
submit.grid()
```

and my full code:

```
 def raise_frame(frame):
        frame.tkraise()

    f1 = tk.Frame(root)
    f2 = tk.Frame(root)
    f3 = tk.Frame(root)
    f4 = tk.Frame(root)
    f5 = tk.Frame(root)

    for frame in (f1,f2,f3,f4,f5):
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')

class MyButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, *args, info=None, command=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs, command=self.callback)

        self.initialCommand = command
        self.info = info

    def display_info(self):
        # Display the information the way you want
        print(self.info)

    def callback(self):
        self.initialCommand()
        self.display_info()



    button1 = tk.Button(f1, text='Ya', command=lambda:raise_frame(f2)).pack()
    button2 = tk.Button(f1, text=Yb', command=lambda:raise_frame(f3)).pack()
    button3 = tk.Button(f1, text=Yc', command=lambda:raise_frame(f4)).pack()
    button4 = tk.Button(f1, text='Yd', command=lambda:raise_frame(f5)).pack()




    tk.Label(f2, text="Ya").pack()
button = tk.Button(root, text="Display info", command=lambda:print("Initial command"))
    button.pack()
    button.info = "Hello, world!"
        tk.Button(f2, text="HOME", command=lambda:raise_frame(f1)).pack()

        tk.Label(f3, text="Yb").pack()
button = tk.Button(root, text="Display info", command=lambda:print("Initial command"))
    button.pack()
    button.info = "Hello, world!"
        tk.Button(f3, text="HOME", command=lambda:raise_frame(f1)).pack()

        tk.Label(f4, text="Yc").pack()
button = tk.Button(root, text="Display info", command=lambda:print("Initial command"))
    button.pack()
    button.info = "Hello, world!"
        tk.Button(f4, text="HOME", command=lambda:raise_frame(f1)).pack()

        tk.Label(f5, text="Yd").pack()
button = tk.Button(root, text="Display info", command=lambda:print("Initial command"))
    button.pack()
    button.info = "Hello, world!"
        tk.Button(f5, text="HOME", command=lambda:raise_frame(f1)).pack()

    raise_frame(f1)
    root.mainloop()

if os.path.isfile(creds):
    Login()
else:
    Signup()
```

Comment: first: you should ask two questions if you have two questions.
second: your `sequentialSearch`-function looks for single items. words in a string are subsequences. your function can only find single characters. So I would suggest you to change the `if`-statement to `if alist[pos:pos+len(list(item))] == list(item):`

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "adding info to a button"?

Comment: Adding text so that once my button is pressed, information appears within the tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to store specific information, related to a specific button, so that when the said button is pressed, the information is displayed somewhere.

You could extend the `Button` class so as to make a wrapper able to hold that information.

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, *args, info=None, command=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs, command=self.callback)

        self.initialCommand = command
        self.info = info

    def display_info(self):
        # Display the information the way you want
        print(self.info)

    def callback(self):
        self.initialCommand()
        self.display_info()
```

This allows you to set the wrapped information whenever you want, by setting the ìnfo` attribute.

Add this class at the beginning of your code, and replace all your `Button` instances by `MyButton` instances.

The new buttons should behave exactly the same as before, except that when pressing them, their `info` attribute will be displayed the way you defined in the `display_info` method, after a call to the command you passed on instanciation.

You need to define the `display_info` according to your needs (print in the console, display in a label...).

---

Here is a short example:

```
root = tk.Tk()
button = MyButton(root, text="Display info", command=lambda:print("Initial command"))
button.pack()
button.info = "Hello, world!"

root.mainloop()
```

The code above displays a root window with a single button. When this button is pressed, `Initial command` is printed in the console, then the `info` attribute, namely `"Hello, world!"` is printed.

Comment: And with my current code, where would I place this for it to work? im facing repetitive errors. Also, I want it that so when you press the button, information appears on the window opened, not on a new one

Comment: @joe I edited my post and the code as well. You will need to define the `display_info` method so the information is actually displayed the way you want.

Comment: i'll edit my code and show you what I have, its still not working. I also get an error message on this line                                                                    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs, command=self.callback)                    from the comma

Comment: @joe All you have to do is 1 - Add the class I gave you to your code, and 2 - Replace `Button` by `MyButton` in your old code. The code after your edit is still full of `Button` calls, but `MyButton` is never called.

Comment: because when I replaced with mybutton, I had the not defined error despite the class being there? it is the class part im stuck with

Comment: Which part of the class function have I added wrongly into my code?

Comment: Your indentation is wrong, which matters in Python. You put all your code *inside* of the `MyButton` class, because you did not un-indent after the class code. Correct this, then replace `tk.Button` by `MyButton` evrywhere (except in the class declaration, of course).

Comment: @joe You're welcome :) If this helped you, don't hesitate to accept the answer, so as to show your problem as solved ;)

Comment: @joe Nope, everything after the class (from `button1 = tk.Button...`) must be unindented, so as to be a part of your main code. Besides, you're still calling `tk.Button`, while the `MyButton` class I gave you is supposed to be used _instead_ of `tk.Button`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143918/discussion-between-joe-and-right-leg).